# how to replace the values of labels in iOS-charts?

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I use IOS-charts for drawing of downloading speed. I give to chart function array of double which has byte values. It build chart. But I want to show in chart labels value in megabytes, kilobytes or byte. I can transform byte in these value with help `NSByteFormatter`. But there is one problem, a function that builds charts takes a single array of values (such as an array of bytes), and outputs the same values in the labels on the chart, I tried to find a solution to do this, but I found none. How can i do this?

Function which draw a chart

```
   func setSendChart(description: [String], value: [Double]) {
    var chartDataEntryArray = [ChartDataEntry]()

    for item in 0..<description.count {
        let chartEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: value[item], xIndex: item)
        chartDataEntryArray.append(chartEntry)
    }

    let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: chartDataEntryArray, label: "")
    dataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
    dataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    dataSet.drawCubicEnabled = true
    dataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
    dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false

    dataSet.fillColor = UIColor(red: 47/255, green: 206/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let chartData = LineChartData(xVals: description, dataSet: dataSet)
    sendChartView.data = chartData
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the value the chart is using to draw; however, you could provide your own `NSNumberFormatter` implementation to get the formatted value you want. `yAxis` has valueFormatter, so does `dataSet`

Another way is, you subclass dataSet to pass your value text array, and override `renderAxisLabels` or `drawValues` to draw the text you want.

I would prefer the first one since it does not touch the library code